# Problem with jax tree_multimap when importing pybamm package

Tags: import, pip, jax

I am trying to import pybamm and its throwing the following error at me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0xWn.png)

Following the suggestion of a previous post I have tried

```
!pip install "jax<=0.3.16" "jaxlib<=0.3.16"
```

but it remains the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tree_multimap was removed in 0.3.16 (see [CHANGELOG](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#jax-0-3-16)), so I believe you'd need to install <=0.3.15 for that import to work